# Title caption (AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE) is not correct when using TaskDialogIndirect with MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, taskdialog

In my STRINGTABLE I have the following:

[image]

In my code where I use `TaskDialogIndirect` I can hover over `AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE`:

[image]

I understand this much ... if the resource can't be found it defaults to the executable name. At the moment that is what I am getting:

[image]

Yet, when I use the `CTaskDialog` constructor I get the correct caption:

[image]

For `TaskDialogIndirect` I am using:

```
sConfig.hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
```

I have also tried:

```
sConfig.hInstance = AfxGetResourceHandle();
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the definition of `HINSTANCE` in the [`TASKDIALOGCONFIG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-taskdialogconfig) it says:

> Handle to the module that contains the icon resource identified by the **pszMainIcon** or **pszFooterIcon** members, and the string resources identified by the **pszWindowTitle**, **pszMainInstruction**, **pszContent**, **pszVerificationText**, **pszExpandedInformation**, **pszExpandedControlText**, **pszCollapsedControlText** or **pszFooter** members.

The hinst was when it stated **pszWindowTitle**! Whilst I was loading the `AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE` into a `CString` I was not assigning it in the structure. I needed:

```
sConfig.pszWindowTitle = strTitle.GetString();
```

And now it is fine:

[image]